# How to calculate the distance from the point to the raster' boundary in qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, point, distance, voronoi-thiessen

As the picture 1 shows,I use the points generate the Voronoi diagrams and change the polygons to the raster.The purpose of me is to calculate the min,max and mean distance from points to the raster'boundary they above(like picture 2).So that I can calculate the variance of every unit.

I do this in order to know the reachability of each grid in the area to the points.The greater the distance and variance, the worse the reachability.Can you help me? Or you have other ways?

[image]

[image]